# ASP .NET Web API Queryable capabilities with deferred execution

Tags: odata, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Should my api method always tie up to the underlying datasource (datacontext of an ORM) to expose Queryable capabilities supporting oData with the benefit of **Deferred Execution**?

Snippet

```
public class ProductController : ApiController { 
    public IQueryable<Product> Get() { 
        var dbContext = new DBContext(); 
        return dbContext.Product.AsQueryable(); 
    } 
}
```

1. If I have to tie the always then, how and where can I apply business validation if I have to ? Eg: I want to return on the Products which are not expired.
2. Aren't we violating the seperation of concerns and doing tight coupling by exposing the data entities directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the rule applied as below:

```
return dbContext.Product.Where(p=> !p.IsExpired).AsQueryable();
```

With regard to your second question, it is up to you. If you need to expose your data, then you should. If you want to expose *an alternate view* of the data, you can create a *ViewModel* and expose that.

Comment: @alistad hoe can you transform to a viewmodel when using defered execution? Lears injects additional expressions in The expression tree...